# Design pattern for writing to various eventlogs

Tags: design-patterns, factory, event-log

We have a system which is composed of few applications.  Each application at certain points need to generate an event to one of event logs.  (Event logs is a table in a database having attributes that define event log number, event type and so on.)  All event logs have certain common attributes, but every log has some specific attributes (so there'll be a sparse table).  Every event log supports its own set of events.  These events dictate which additional fields are to be written.  Application knows event log number and event type it must generate at certain points of execution.

I'm looking for design patterns which will help us achieve this.  We need to write a library usable by applications, so each developer will have an easy to use classes for the purpose of inserting event data.  Speaking at the "code level", I want to reduce client code to call to a single method with a signature specific to event it needs to generate.
So far I came up with a Factory (most likely it'll be also a Singleton) which will have 10 methods (10 event logs).  Each method generates an appropriate class (say, EventLog1Entry) which will provide method for writing data to db.
What to do further I do not know.
Any suggestions?

P.S. This is my first attempt to use some design pattern, so forgive me if I use professional terms too freely.

Comment: Observer is good for several-to-many (e.g. it is unknown how many event logs we'll have and which will subscribe to what). Here we have several-to-several, so I don't think this is the most fitting pattern.

Comment: Thank you.  Would have never thought of that one)

Comment: I've read a bit on an Observer pattern and it seem to model situation when subscribed objects need to be notified on Subject's (Observable) change of state.  I don't see how it applies to my problem.  Client needs to write data about what it's doing.  I could simply write static class with static methods but there would be about 80 of them and developers would go crazy picking the one they need.  I'll look closer at events though, may be about 10 will suffice.

Comment: exactly my point. Please take a look at my answer, it's much simpler than you would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) - it already supports everything you want and in addition is highly optimized and extensively tested.

Even if you don't want to just use it "as is", it may give you some pointers on which design has proven itself over the years.

Comment: Althought this is not an answer to the posted problem in terms of a design architecture, this link might be useful.

Comment: I don't see the possibility for inserting other fields with log4net besides message string.  We have system specific fields in db.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are :) `log.Warn(new MsgObj(42, "So long and thanks for all the fish"));` from the examples solution - you can log ANY object, your custom appender can then unpack the different objects as needed. Writing them to SQL is, of course, also supported.